# What ( fast ) algorithm for evaluating a nine point DFT could be used?

Tags: fourier-analysis

What ( fast ) algorithm for evaluating a nine point DFT could be used?
$$
G={V^{(9)}\over{\sqrt{9}}}g=\begin{bmatrix}
 &1  &1  &\cdots  &1  &1 \\ 
 &z_0  &z_1  &\cdots  &z_7  &z_8 \\
 &z_0^2  &z_1^2  &\cdots  &z_7^2  &z_8^2 \\ 
 &\vdots  &\vdots  &  &\vdots  &\vdots \\ 
 &z_0^8  &z_1^8  &\cdots  &z_7^8  &z_8^8 \\  
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
g_0\\ 
g_1\\ 
g_2\\ 
\vdots\\ 
g_8\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Where
$$
z_k=exp(2\pi i k / 9), \
k=0,1,2,...,8
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce it to 3 blocks of dimension 3 DFT's a la Coley-Tukey. However, it is questionable if at these low dimensions there is really a gain in complexity.